# Unique ID for client computer using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a website using asp.net with c#, and for that I want to get an unique ID for each client PC. Right now I am getting this by using client ip address but when pc is connected on LAN then that all pc having the same ip address. So how can I identify clients uniquely, in order to associate a request to a given client?

Comment: Use a cookie on first visit ?

Comment: You can use client certificates. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315588

Comment: but can i access cookies from my window application? and suppose cookies for browser is desable then this will ocure a problem also.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a session id and assign it to each user. For each session you can generate a GUID and use this a unique key for each user.

Comment: I think the OP needs a persistent uniqueness, i.e. not only on the session level.

Comment: I am not understand OP means?

Comment: On my situation i am open my window application based on this ip address so this is not usefull for me.i want some uniq identification which i also get from window application.Example:local ip address and live ip address i am getting from window application but from web application i am getting only live ip not local ip.

Comment: @mayur: "OP" means either "Original Poster" (that's you in this case) or sometimes "Original Post" (your question) depending on context.

Comment: @mayur- Even if its a window application you can create a GUID and use this as the unique key. If you can describe the exact requirement and your architecture/scenario I will be able to understand it  better

Comment: Suppose user click on any supplier on website for chat with him.i want to open chat window of that supplier from my window application.this all the thing is working fine because i am checking ip address and supplier id.but when user is on lan connection then ip address is same for that all user connected on lan and if any one click on supplier id,supplier chat window will open to all the lan connected pc.this is only the problem.if i give any idea by which i find pc from wich request is comming then this is good for me.

Comment: Got it. So all you need is to maintain a dictionary of active users. and i am pretty much sure that you can do it via generating a unique id for each user. So if there is a new chat request coming up assign a unique id and then use this id to differentiate with other requets. I dont think IP address is a good choice.

Comment: ya but based on IP address window chat messenger(which is install on pc) can find that this request is comming from my ip so i have to open this supplier.because ip address i can also find from window application other wise uniq id how i can maintain on window application also.so if i use uniq id then my window application how can open that supplier chat window.

Comment: Sorry Mayur but i wasnt able to understand your comment. Anyways if you can reply to following.  I understand that you have to implement some kind of a chat messenger. Your solution is a thin client (web application) or a thick client (windows app) what communication model are you using

Comment: hello gaurav, i am using thick client model(window app) for open chat window of clicked supplier from website.